# Handlebars Doesn't Work on Phonegap Mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, handlebars.js, phonegap-desktop-app

I am building a PhoneGap app using version 0.4.2.

I use Handlebars templates in my code, which I compile using this line:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#myTemplateName").html());
```

The app functions as expected on desktop and mobile browsers, but when I try to test the mobile version using the PhoneGap Developer App (version 1.7.6), that line doesn't work.  The console doesn't show any error output, but I think the app must be crashing because the app becomes non-responsive and any alerts after that line of code don't show up.

I also tried precompiling the handlebars templates and getting them using this line:

```
var template = Handlebars.templates["myTemplateName"];
```

I get the same response: the app works perfectly fine in browsers, but mysteriously stops working on mobile.

Why is this happening?

Other potentially useful information:

- Along with PhoneGap, I'm also using jQuery Mobile
- I'm using Handlebars version 4.0.5
- jQuery Mobile, Handlebars, and the Handlebars templates are included in my index.html file in script tags (in that order).

**Edit:** As requested, here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="body">

    <!-- Visible Page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="home">If this is visible it's not working.</div>

    <!-- Handlebars Library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>

    <!-- Handlebars Template -->
    <script id="template-content" type="text/x-handlebars-template">{{data}}</script>

    <!-- jQuery Mobile -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PhoneGap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var myTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#template-content").html());
            $("#home").html(myTemplate({data:"It's working!"}));
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

On browsers I see "It's working" but using the PhoneGap Developer mobile app I see "If this is visible it's not working."

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap is probably changing `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="file://js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>`

Change it to `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars-v4.0.5.js"></script>`

Also make sure that jQuery is working, as you are using a CDN it's possible that Phonegap is not downloading it